# I want to update result everytime, but can't understand how can I do it

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am just learning jQuery from an app. I have a problem in my shopping list program. Whenever I add some price, it shows me results in a string; like if I add 5 and 7 it shows me "512" in the text box. But I want to update it every time users add or remove anything.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Shopping List</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="New item" id="item" />
    <input type="number" placeholder="Price" id="price"/>
    <button id="add">Add</button>
    <ol id="mylist"></ol>
    <div>Total = ₹<textarea id="cartTotal" placeholder="0" disabled></textarea></div>
</body>
```

Here is my script,

```
var priceTotal = 0;
$(function() {
$("#add").on("click", function() {

    var val = $("#item").val();
    var prc = parseInt($("#price").val());

    priceTotal += prc;
    $("textarea").append(priceTotal);
```

Full code is [here](https://code.sololearn.com/WDg07908723Q/?ref=app). I didn't find any suitable answers anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The append method on the Textarea field will always add the current value onto the end of the existing value. Text in the `<textarea>` will be displayed between the tags, e.g: `<textarea>Example</textarea>`.

So we can simply replace the append method with the below code:

```
var priceTotal = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function() {
            $('#add').on('click', function() {
                var val = $("#item").val();
                var prc = parseInt($("#price").val());

                priceTotal += prc;
                $('textarea').html(priceTotal);
            });
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sir, It's working! Thank you so much!! Love your reply!☺️